# Error while installing mysqlclient in py3

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, mysql-python

```
    rohit@rohit:~/Desktop/django_project$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.12
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6bic4vtr/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6bic4vtr/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6bic4vtr/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6bic4vtr/mysqlclient/
```

I've also tried install with version `pip3 install mysqlclient==1.3.12`, it shows same error.

Comment: "mysql_config not found" you will have to install it with your OS installer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+mysql_config+not+found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"mysql_config not found and mysql-config is in a different package, which can be installed from

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```